# Turning user authentication off in nginx for GraphQL api for Gatsby site

Tags: nginx, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to set up user authentication on my Gatsby site, but allow for the GraphQL api.

Here's what I have now:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location "^~ /api/.*" {
       auth_basic "off";
    }
}
```

EDIT, based on comments below

I tried to add what's in location ~ .php$ as well as what's in rewrites, but got the same error.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location ^~ /api/ {
        rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
        auth_basic off;
    }
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
}

# PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;

     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

     # below for some setups on php 7.4
     #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is quoting `off`.

Just remove the quotes: change `"off"` to `off`. Then it will be an actual `off` configuration as opposed to the quoted string.

The other is the non-regex location (`^~`) for `/api/`.
The `location ^~` best to be explained as a prefix location with the highest priority.
It is not a regular expression type of location.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}

location ^~ /api/ {
   auth_basic off;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;

   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

   # below for some setups on php 7.4
   #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
}

# PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;

     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

     # below for some setups on php 7.4
     #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error with this when i build ```"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle: reporter is not defined 41 | // Handle errors 42 | if (result.errors) { > 43 | reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`) | ^ 44 | return; 45 | } 46 | Make sure that you don't have a typo somewhere and use valid arguments in createPages lifecycle. Learn more about createPages here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages```

Comment: Naturally, you'll need whatever `proxy_pass`/`fastcgi_pass`, etc. directives you have in `@rewrites` location copied to `location ^~ /api/`. So that the API requests are actually being forwarded to the app.

Comment: I added it as you can see in the edits. Still giving me the same error. I added all of the params under ```location ~ \.php$``` as well as what's in rewrites, and also got the same error.

Comment: See update. `fastcgi_pass` should be in the API  location.